# Is it worth it to repair or is it better to buy?

Tags: gears, pedals, identify-this-bike

I found an old bike on my grandpa's house and since i am in need of a decent bike i wanted to know if the bike was good enough to be refurbished (new gears, pedals, brakes, tires etc.) or if would be better to just buy a new one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it needs all that stuff?  It obviously needs a seat ($25), and the chain needs cleaning and oiling.  The cogs don't look worn.  Tires look good from here -- should not be badly cracked yet, and certainly aren't worn.  And I don't see anything wrong with the pedals.

Comment: Yeah, if it fits, put some oil on the chain, some air in the tires, a new seat (and seatpost if you don't have the bit on the top for the seatpost) for about 40 bucks and then you're good to go.

Comment: The rear derailleur is some old junk that doesn't belong to this bike, makes maintenance more difficult than it needs to be and probably won't index correctly with the shifters. Since a new entry level derailleur costs less than 20 euros, I would replace it immediately.

Comment: @ojs good spotting - the rear derailler is not even connected to the hanger; instead someone's shoved it on the axle.   OP the rear derauller would normally be fastened into that big threadded hole which is below the rear axle.  However if it works as-is then changing it is your choice.

Comment: Your bike could be anything from 2001-2013 according to http://bikepedia.com/Search.aspx?Q=gt%20avalanche%201.0  probably earlier, based on the fork boots and the V brakes.   Looks like a nice ride when its done.   Fix up/replace the minimum to get it useable, and then replace other parts later if they fail.   You're up for a seat post and a saddle.  I'd suspect the brake pads need changing cos they harden up with age.  Photos suggest tyres are good.  Inflate tyres and leave overnight to see if they are still up in the morning.  Some lube wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: @Criggie it's called claw mount, and it's used on old French bikes or when you have broken the derailleur hanger and can't be bothered to find a replacement. In this case, the hanger looks intact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few things you could do-

1. Get a new seat and seat post.
2. Ride the bike and see if anything sounds or feels amiss. Places to look out for are the moving arts like headset(handle), the drive train and the brakes.
3. The drive train seems to be in prime condition except for rust. Spray some WD-40 or equivalent rust remover on anything thats rusty and make sure you wipe off the extra cleanly. Then lube the whole drive train.
4. Your brakes will need replacing for sure, best not to take risks with safety.

You will have to decide the worthwhileness of the project for yourself. Money wise it won't cost much more than $50 (~20 for the seat, and the rest for brake pads and other implements like WD-40 if you don't have them). I would personally do it less to save money but more for the learning that would be gained from doing it. But the importance given to learning experiences differ from person to person and its up to you

Comment: Use chain lube for chains please, not generic water-displacer.

Comment: WD-40 is not a "rust remover".  The one thing that WD-40 is good for is cleaning really badly gunked derailers, but after using it one must wipe it all off and thoroughly lubricate with chain lube.  To dissolve rust you can try oxalic acid, either in a scouring powder (Barkeeper's Friend) or as a water solution in a spray.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I use WD40 regularly as rust remover, spray it on, wait for about 15 sec and then rub off with a rag cloth, it works.

Comment: @c10yas - You are mistaken.  WD-40 is pretty good for loosening dried-on grease, but will not do anything to remove rust.  If it's removing something for you, it's not rust.